# Need to develop a HTML page with Server side Events and can be shared across websites

Tags: asp.net

I Need to develop a HTML page with Server side Events(like database save) and the page can be reused across websites(cross domain).

I don't prefer the logic of having a (user control)dll as deployment is a issue, so i would prefer to have a single point of deployement.

can i store the UI somewhere like database and send it via web service.

Please get me some help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here I will suggest you to

create a simple blank HTML page to share across website.
keep the content in database and populate accordingly
Create a java script file for communication with server(s) based on the condition, that will make more sense